# Create build config string field in android library?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I want to to have a string version in build config for my library module

I am using the below code

```
android {
ext{
    version = 'NW-1.1.6'
    name = 'Network'
}
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "String", "LIBRARY_VERSION","${version}"
}
```

But in my build config I see it as

```
public static final String LIBRARY_VERSION = NW-1.1.6;
```

instead of

```
public static final String LIBRARY_VERSION = "NW-1.1.6";
```

What is wrong with the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "String", "LIBRARY_VERSION","\"${version}\""
}
```

this will produces the string you need:

```
public static final String LIBRARY_VERSION = "NW-1.1.6";
```